# print a char* in multiple lines with ncurses?

Tags: c, char, ncurses

I'm working in [c](/questions/tagged/c) and have a string, say "111222333" and i want that printed as a box with [ncurses](/questions/tagged/ncurses). How can this be accomplished?

`111`
`222`
`333`

Given:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
    const char* const c = "111222333";

    initscr();
    cbreak();

    // ... ?

    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: String literals should only be pointed to by a `const char *`.

Comment: Sorry, i thought the question was implied.

Answer (score 0):

If the string is always a const char *, you can format it by inserting \n where required (e.g. "111\n222\n333\n"). When printed, this will give you the box shape.

If you are asking how to created a boxed object in ncurses, you can use [mvprintw](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/printw.html) in a new window, then use box() to create a border around it. [This example](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/keys.html#SIMPLEKEYEX) shows how to create a boxed menu; the same technique would apply here, if I'm understanding your question.